# Select and insert JSON file into SQL Server table

Tags: mysql, .net, sql-server, json, database

I'm trying to import the entirety of a JSON file into a table of mine in SQL Server.

The JSON data looks like this:

```
{
  "category": "General Knowledge",
  "type": "multiple",
  "difficulty": "hard",
  "question": "Electronic music producer Kygo&#039;s popularity skyrocketed after a certain remix. Which song did he remix?",
  "correct_answer": "Ed Sheeran - I See Fire",
  "incorrect_answers": [
    "Marvin Gaye - Sexual Healing",
    "Coldplay - Midnight",
    "a-ha - Take On Me"
  ]
},
```

With multiple entries like this. 
I'm attempting to use `OPENROWSET` and `OPENJSON` to accomplish this using the following query:

```
SELECT value
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\general_questions.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
```

However, the output I'm getting only shows the first question object in the file. I have a two part question:

**How can I get my query to select ALL of the objects in the file and then insert all of those objects into a table in my SQL Server db?**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, is it this:

```
SELECT value
 FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\general_questions.json', SINGLE_CLOB) as j
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
WITH 
(
CATEGORY VARCHAR2(MAX),
...
) AS JSON_TABLE
```

Also, am not sure what you mean by "However, the output I'm getting only shows the first question object in the file."? Do you mean the question object has multiple attributes?